# Let $A, B, C \in \mathbb{C}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $A^{n} = B^{n} = C^{n} = 1$ and $A + B + C = 0$, then $n$ is a multiple of 3.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

I think the problem is clear from the title. It included a hint which suggested reducing it to the case $A = 1$, but so far I've come up with little.

It is quite direct from the statement that $A, B, C$ are $n$th roots of unity. I also know that the sum of $n$th roots of unity must be zero, but haven't found a way to link it to 3 dividing $n$.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dividing through by $A$ and renaming, we get $B^n=C^n=1$ and $1+B+C=0$, so that $B+C=-1$.

Then if $B=r+si$, $C=(-1-r)-si$, and the fact that $|B| = |C|=1$ quickly shows that $r = -\frac{1}{2}$. Thus $B$ is a cube root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the $n$-roots of unity are forming a $n$-regular polygone on the plane.
The condition $A+B+C=0$ is equivalent to say that the points $A,B,C$ are forming an equilateral triangle on the plane.

Now the regular $n$-polygones such that you can find an equilateral triangle with three of its vertices must have $3k$ vertices. (For some $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$)

Perhaps do you look for a less geometric argument ?

Comment: I must admit I'm not very good at making (or understanding) geometric arguments. Could you elaborate a bit on how you know that "the condition $A + B + C = 0$ is equivalent to say that the points $A, B, C$ are forming an equilateral triangle on the plane" ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\cos\frac{2\pi m}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi m}{n}$, $B=\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}$ and $C=\cos\frac{2\pi l}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi l}{n}$,

where $n\geq m\geq k\geq l\geq0$.

Thus,
$$\cos\frac{2\pi m}{n}+\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}+\cos\frac{2\pi l}{n}=0$$ and
$$\sin\frac{2\pi m}{n}+\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}+\sin\frac{2\pi l}{n}=0.$$
Hence,
$$\left(\cos\frac{2\pi m}{n}+\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)^2+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi m}{n}+\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)^2=\cos^2\frac{2\pi l}{n}+\sin^2\frac{2\pi l}{n}$$ or
$$\cos^2\frac{2\pi m}{n}+2\cos\frac{2\pi m}{n}\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}+\cos^2\frac{2\pi k}{n}+\sin^2\frac{2\pi m}{n}+2\sin\frac{2\pi m}{n}\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}+\sin^2\frac{2\pi k}{n}=\cos^2\frac{2\pi l}{n}+\sin^2\frac{2\pi l}{n}$$ or
$$2+2\cos\frac{2\pi(m-k)}{n}=1$$ or
$$\cos\frac{2\pi(m-k)}{n}=-\frac{1}{2},$$ 
which gives that $n$ divided by $3$.

Comment: How do you go from  
$\left(\cos\frac{2\pi m}{n}+\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)^2+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi m}{n}+\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)^2=\cos^2\frac{2\pi l}{n}+\sin^2\frac{2\pi l}{n}$
  to $\cos\frac{2\pi(m-k)}{n}=-\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: @math_at_you I fixed my post. See now.